# Count the number of isosceles triangles

Tags: geometry

How can I count the amount of isosceles triangles fitting by the following criteria: the base of the triangles equals 1, all the angles are natural numbers and are less than $75^\circ$. (The equilateral triangle is counted only once)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: An isosceles triangle is uniquely determined by its base length and the angle next to the base.

Comment: So is that just 74 triangles by the cosine theorem?

Comment: You wanted all angles less than 75, so for example (120, 30, 30) is impossible

Comment: I have counted that the amount is 22 triangles.

Comment: @Student12 From $53^\circ$ to $74^\circ$ inclusive, there are indeed $22$ different possible angles.

Answer (score 1):

If each of the base angles is $n^\circ$ and the third angle is $(180-2n)^\circ$ then you want

- $n$ an integer
- $n \lt 75$
- $180 -2n \lt 75$, i.e. $n \gt 52.5$

Comment: So, $22$? One for each $n$ from $53$ to $74$, inclusive?

Comment: Yes - and the other angle is even numbers from $32$ to $74$ inclusive

Answer (score -1):

If the angle opposite the base is $x$ degrees, the angles at the base are $\frac{180-x}{2}$. Do a little arithmetic to determine when that is less than $75$, that will give you bounds on $x$ then it's simple to figure out how many integer values $x$ can take.

Comment: $x$ being odd would not work as it would make the other angles fractional

Comment: Right, probably better to start with one of the angles at the base then.